# Regex statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have certain column names that are named

```
car_model1
car_model2
bike_model1
bike_model2
```

I'm trying to regex just the part before the "_" but my regex statement isn't working in SQL Server 2008.

I have:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'dt_model_data'
  and COLUMN_NAME like '%([^\_]+)%'
```

This doesn't return anything but in python this regex statement works. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Why a regex? `WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_model%'` works fine.

Comment: I'll take it! However, what if the part after the "_" varies so you can have "_model" or "_brand"?

Comment: Yes, you are missing that regex isn't supported in SQL Server like that. Very limited abilities exist with the `LIKE` operator. Based on your other comment, then you are only looking for an underscore... `LIKE '%!_%' ESCAPE '!'` since an underscore is any single character in the `LIKE` clause.

Comment: `COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_model%'  OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_brand%'`.

Comment: that solves it. For a second I was about to re-read my finite state automata notes

Comment: @KenWhite remember underscore needs to be escaped. It's a wildcard character with the like clause.

Comment: @scsimon: Yes, you're right. Missed that. Thanks. (Too late to edit the comments, though.)